# Формат логов в spool

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Есть несколько небольших файлов:

1) run.bat

```
SET NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
SQLPLUS MYUSER/mypassword@mybase @run.sql
```

2) run.sql

```
set verify off
set serveroutput on size 1000000
set linesize 192
set trim on
set trims on
set feedback off

spool log.txt;
@select_text.sql;
spool off;
prompt download completed;
exit;
```

3) select_text.sql

```
SELECT '<row>
    <MT_ID>' || v_table.MT_ID || '</MT_ID>
    <DEF>' || v_table.DEF || '</DEF>
</row>' FROM MYTABLE v_table;
```

В результате запуска батника в лог попадает подобное содержимое:

```
НАЗВАНИЕ СТОЛБЦА
---------------------------
содержимое_1
содержимое_1

содержимое_2
содержимое_2

содержимое_3
НАЗВАНИЕ СТОЛБЦА
---------------------------
содержимое_3

содержимое_4
содержимое_4
```

То есть все содержимые (несколько строк) разделяются переносом строки и время от времени втыкается название столбца с подчеркиванием (может даже посреди значения). Как избавиться от этого и получить:

```
содержимое_1
содержимое_1
содержимое_2
содержимое_2
содержимое_3
содержимое_3
содержимое_4
содержимое_4
```

Comment: Используйте: set pagesize  0

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо! А есть ли способ удалить перевод строки между содержимыми?

Comment: Да, нашел. set recsep off; Огонь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в начало файла run.sql

```
pagesize 0
recsep off
```